# Laravel : errors is not showing

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-route

I am using resource in laravel and i wanna a custom uri route for (show) action my route is:

```
Route::resource('/admin/users', 'UsersController')->except(['show']);
Route::get('/admin/users/{user}/show', 'UsersController@show')->name('users.show');
```

i checking a test url but not showing Error 404 in this Route
for example :

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/users/test
```

show this error

```
The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: PUT, PATCH, DELETE.
```

When I delete the code except(['show']) My code is working properly and shows a 404 error
but my Route List Show Two Route for show action

```
|        | GET|HEAD  | backend/users/{user}      | backend.users.show 
|        | GET|HEAD  | backend/users/{user}/show | backend.users.show
```

Comment: Use your `users.show` route before resource route.

Comment: Have you tried to replace your `->except` by: `->only(['index', 'create', 'store', 'update', 'destroy'])`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to this problem

Edit this file :

> /app/Exceptions/Handler.php

Add this line

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException;
```

And

```
public function render($request, Throwable $exception)
{
if ($exception instanceof MethodNotAllowedHttpException) 
         {
        abort(404);
         }
         return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your both roure URI pattern are same, so you need to the define the route before the `resource` route :

```
Route::get('/admin/users/{user}/show', 'UsersController@show')->name('users.show');
Route::resource('/admin/users', 'UsersController')->except(['show']);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because your route is NOT a 404 error as when you're using `::resource` when creating a route, it uses the same route as `show()` as it does with the `update()` and `destroy()` methods but with a different request verb.

```
GET         /photos/{photo}
PUT/PATCH.  /photos/{photo}
DELETE      /photos/{photo}
```

Read more about this in the documentation https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/controllers#resource-controllers

When you specify `except(['show'])` you're removing the get route but the route still exists for the PUT/PATCH and DELETE methods.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `except(['show'])` with

```
  ->only(['index', 'create', 'store', 'update', 'destroy'])
```

That will work fine in your case.